# How do I make this function to return list of all docs in collection in an array. I am using mongoldb with bluebird?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bluebird

1.the function below should return all documents in collection report in an array.

```
function listdocs(){
        var valuess=[];
        MongoClient.connectAsync(murl).then(function(db) {


        return db.collection('reports').find({}).toArrayAsync();
        }).then(function(reports) {
            valuess=reports;


        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });

    return valuess;
    }
```

Comment: whats the error that you are getting?

Comment: I am getting valuess as an empty array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know in Node.js everything is async, so if you call `listdocs()` it will return even before `MongoClient.connectAsync` returns. So you need to change `listdocs` to accept a callback that will be called when the results are fetched.

Here is how the code should look like:

```
function listdocs(callback) {
    MongoClient.connectAsync(murl).then(function(db) {
        return db.collection('reports').find({}).toArrayAsync();
    }).then(function(reports) {
        callback(null, reports)
    }).catch(function(err) {
        callback(err, null);
    });
}
```

And after that you can call the function like this:

```
listdocs(function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        // do something with the error
    }

    // do something with the result
});
```

Comment: Works perfect :) Thanks